# Why is my program not eliminating a sum of a list that should be eliminated?

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

When we input `x = 1, y = 1, z = 1` and `n = 2`, there's one result that shouldn't be printed but it doesn't happen.

`[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]` <- last result

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())

list1 = [ 
    [i,j,k] 
    for i in range(x+1)
    for j in range(y+1)
    for k in range(z+1)
]

list1.sort()
print(list1)

for subList in list1:
    if sum(subList) == n:
        list1.remove(subList)
```

it shouldn't print the `sublist = [1,1,0]`, the sum is 2, despite my command:  `if sum(subList) == n:`

What should I do?

Comment: Removing elements from a list while looping over it is generally a bad idea.

Comment: To be clear, your goal is to end up with a list of lists where the sub lists that add up to n have been filtered out?

Comment: @rhurwitz you're right, that was my purpose

Comment: Hard to get the formatting right in a comment, but if you put this line at the end of your `list1` list comprehension it should keep out the sub lists that sum to n:     `if i + j + k != n`

Comment: @rhurwitz thank you! it's worked. I understood my mistake, when the program removed an element (sublist), its index had changed, so, it wasn't interated in the execution.